# Plugin DataTable not working in Laravel 8

Tags: datatables, laravel-8

I'm new in web development and in Laravel 8 and I'm having trouble when using the DataTable plugin

I had read the documentation that is in this link https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

Going to show the code I have and I think I'm not doing anything wrong so dunno why it isnt working.

This is from the app.blade in the scripts

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.8.0/main.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en'
                    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/mdDateTimePicker.css') }}">
    @yield('css_extra')


</head>
```

As you can see I'm importing Jquery

This is the code of my view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container my-5">
    <h1>Gestión Médicos</h1>
</div>
<div class="container my-5">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-body" href="{{route('medico.create')}}">Registrar Médico</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover bg-white" id="medicos">
            <tr class="info">
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Cedula</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Especialidades</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
                <th>Género</th>
                <th colspan="2">Opciones</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($medicos as $key=>$medico)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$medico->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$medico->apellido}}</td>
                    <td>{{$medico->cedula}}</td>
                    <td>{{$medico->Users->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$medico->email}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach ($medico->Persona_especialidad as $especialidad)
                            {{$medico->Persona_especiaidad}}
                            {{$especialidad->nombre}}
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$medico->telefono}}</td>
                    <td>{{$medico->genero}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('medico.edit', $medico->id)}}">Editar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('medico.borrar', $medico->id)}}">Borrar</a></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
@if (request()->get('mensaje'))
    <script>
        alert('{{request()->get('mensaje')}}')
    </script>
@endif
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#medicos').DataTable();
</script>
@endsection
```

What am I getting this console error?
I don't have a clue what is wrong.

[image: console error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the columns doesn't match. One solution is to have both links for Editar and Borrar in only one `<td>`.

Code the `<tr>` that has the `<th>` like this

```
 <tr class="info">
     <th>Nombre</th>
     <th>Apellido</th>
     <th>Cédula</th>
     <th>Usuario</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Especialidades</th>
     <th>Teléfono</th>
     <th>Género</th>
     <th style="width: 20%">Opciones</th>
 </tr>
```

And also code the `<td>` that has the links like this

```
<td><a href="{{route('medico.edit', $medico->id)}}" style="color:blue">Editar</a>
<a href="{{route('medico.borrar', $medico->id)}}" style="color:blue">Borrar</a></td>
```

That would make the two links appear in the same `<td>` and solve the issue because now the `<td>` match in the body and in the head of the table.